# Updating app engine project code

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to google app engine and python. I have created an application in python with the help of google app engine.

i am using cmmand 'appcfg.py update myapp/' from command prompt to update live code. this command was working perfectly but suddenly it stops working. Now every time i run this command it opens up the appcfg.py file. Please help me what is happening with the command

Comment: You've almost certainly told your OS (I'm guessing Windows) to associate `.py` files with your editor instead of the python interpreter.

Comment: yes i am using Windows, but how can i get rid of this error

Comment: yes i solved that issue, that was my mistake. It was using an editot for running the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `python appcfg.py update myapp/`

Comment: @user1340596 do a full path c:\python27\python.exe if your don't have that folder install python 2.7